# Comparing Object, include Computername in output but do not use it

Tags: xml, powershell, compare, compareobject

I want powershell to Compare a few XML files that contain services, status and computernames. That include all of these in the output but only use Name and Status for comparison.
The Idea is to get an output like so:

`Name                  Status      SideIndicator     PSComputername
    ----                  ------      -------------     --------------
    Appinfo               Running     <=

    Appinfo               Stopped     =>

    AudioEndpointBuilder  Stopped     =>

    AudioEndpointBuilder  Running     <=`

As you can see the table looks nice but it doesn't include the computernames...
Anybody got an idea to help out?
This is what the code looks like.

```
$WBService1 = Invoke-Command  $WB1 -Credential ($WBCred) -ScriptBlock {Get-      Service} |
    Select-Object Name, Status, DisplayName, PSComputerName |
    Sort-Object Name
 $WBService2 = Invoke-Command  $WB2 -Credential ($WBCred) -ScriptBlock {Get-Service} |
    Select-Object Name, Status, DisplayName, PSComputerName |
        Sort-Object Name
$WBService1 | Export-Clixml $FileOutput\WBService1.xml
$WBService2 | Export-Clixml $FileOutput\WBService2.xml
$Service1 = Import-Clixml $FileOutput\WBService1.xml
$Service2 = Import-Clixml $FileOutput\WBService2.xml
Compare-Object $Service1 $Service2 -Property Name, Status | Sort-Object Name | Format-     Table -AutoSize Name, Status, Sideindicator, PSComputername
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add -Passthru to Compare-Object to get the extra fields:

```
Compare-Object $Service1 $Service2 -Property Name, Status -Passthru
```

Example:

```
PS> (compare $a $b -property name,status -PassThru |sort name)[0] |ft -a name,status,sideindicator,pscomputername

Name                      Status  SideIndicator PSComputerName
----                      ------  ------------- --------------
AdobeFlashPlayerUpdateSvc Stopped <=            adil-win8
```

I'm just showing 1 to save space.